# Previous and next month not working as expected

Tags: php

I have the following code in order to create a previous and next month links:

```
$date = mktime( 0, 0, 0, date("m"), 1, date("y") );
$nextMonth  = strftime( '%B', strtotime( '+1 month', $date ) );
$prevMonth  = strftime( '%B', strtotime( '-1 month', $date ) );
$nextYear   = strftime( '%Y', strtotime( '+1 month', $date ) );
$prevYear   = strftime( '%Y', strtotime( '-1 month', $date ) );
```

Now when i get to december

```
 the next year variable 2016
 the previous year variable 2015
```

But when the date is now january 2016

```
 the next year variable 2015
 the previous year variable 2014
```

I can't understand why its doing that or what i am doing wrong here. Any one have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: https://eval.in/384578

Comment: https://eval.in/384585   >>  I rewrote your date code to a function that accepts month and year as params, and it is outputting correctly.  (updated link to show the current month/year passed relative to output. indented with `>`.

Comment: You are the man, thats exactly what i was looking for thnks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Testing your function with fixed parameters, you'll get :

```
$date = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2016);
```

and echo $nextYear will not give you 2016 because you only added 1 month. Testing it does what's scripted :

```
the next year variable 2016 // which is january 2016 + 1 month = february 2016
the previous year variable 2015 // jan 2016 - 1 month = dec 2015
```

My guess is you are passing date('Y') without realizing it's 2015